# What would you call a mid-life crisis in someone's 30s?

Tags: single-word-requests

We all know "mid-life crisis" and there's the handy "Quarter-life crisis" for a person around 25 but what would be the appropriate term for a "1/3 life" crisis, ie, a crisis in one's 30s? My Latin roots are weak. Foreign loan words accepted!

Comment: I'd call it a mid-life crisis. Life expectancy varies around the world but it;s typically in the 70-80 range these days, so the "middle" of that is 35-40.

Comment: I'm expected to live into my 90s. So the question still stands: if quarter-life is 1/4 and half-life is 1/2, what is 1/3-life? is just...third-life?  That doesn't sound right grammatically?

Comment: Maybe they’re just having theirs *early*.

Comment: I don't think "mid-life" is supposed to refer to the specific halfway point between birth and death, it just refers to the middle phase of your life when you're (hopefully) well established in adulthood but not yet retired - which could reasonably include at least ages 35-55 even if you do live well into your 90s.

Comment: I'd call it an "early midlife crisis."

Comment: Just call it a crisis.

Answer (score 1):

The expression “[quarter-life crisis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarter-life_crisis)” appears  to be used in psychology to refer also to those in their early to mid-thirties:

> In popular psychology, a quarter-life crisis is a crisis "involving anxiety over the direction and quality of one's life" which is most commonly experienced ***in a period ranging from a person's early twenties up to their mid-thirties.***

(Wikipedia)

[Midlife crisis](https://neurospatms.com/signs-you-are-experiencing-depression-vs-a-midlife-crisis/) appears to refers to people from 35
to 55:

> The most common midlife crisis age range is 35 to 55, with some variability between genders.

(neurospatms.com)

Comment: Thanks for that, but I'm more wondering, what is the grammatically correct way to conjugate "third-of-life" ? If quarter-life is 1/4 and half-life is 1/2, what is 1/3-life? is just...third-life? That doesn't sound right grammatically?

Comment: @Sally - In terms of grammar, "third-life" seems just as valid as "quartet-life". It could imply reincarnation into your third life, but when you add "crisis" then "third-life crisis" would likely be taken the way you intend given "mid-life crisis" is a very well known term.